# How to create a rule that forwards people who access sharepoint.domain.com (for example) to our default SharePoint Online page?

Tags: redirect, sharepoint, 301-redirect

We're using SharePoint online and we're trying to avoid using the default domain used by Microsoft. Also the default domain happens to be an old one. I've tried to create an IIS site which would do the redirect, but no success. Also, I've tried to use CNAME, still no results.

Answer (score 1):

Just changing the DNS CNAME would not work. This will give SSL/TLS Certificate warnings and also the SharePoint Online server has no idea how to handle this unknown domain virtual host.

AFAIK setting a custom (sub-)domain name for SharePoint online is not possible. (Although last time i checked was in 2018)

Another approach is to use a Redirect in IIS.
Configuring a redirect is possible with the following steps:

1. In internet services manager, right click on the file or folder you wish to redirect then select "Properties"
2. Select the radio titled "a redirection to a URL".
3. Enter the redirection page
4. Check "The exact url entered above" and the "A permanent redirection for this resource"
5. Click on 'Apply'

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your help. It worked instantly!